# Passing one vector element as function parameter

Tags: c++, vector

i would like to pass a vector element at a certain position as a function argument, to generate a string. With that string I would like to open a file.
Right now my vector is filled with some strings, I print them with cout, the user should type a number and with the vector element at this position should the other function be called.

```
vector <string> kurzbez;                    //vector definition

void datei_oeffnen(string* var[]);          //function definition

cout << ("Bitte die Zahl eingeben") << endl;     
cin >> kurs_auswahl;                        //Type in Number
cout << endl;

datei_oeffnen(kurzbez.at(kurs_auswahl))     //function call with problem
```

I expect that the function is called with the vector element at the specific iterator.

The result i'm getting is this error at compiling: 69   41  D:\main.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'std::string** {aka std::basic_string**}' for argument '1' to 'void datei_oeffnen(std::string**)'

I've tried to wrap my head around that error and searched several days, but to no avail. Could somebody more knowledgeable help me?
I'm using Dev-C++  5.8.2 with GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: The error is telling you that your `std::string` from `kurzbez.at(kurs_auswahl)` is not correct for the function accepting a `string* var[]` parameter. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: You are passing in a `string`.  The function's argument is `string**`.  What happens if you change the function's argument from `string**` to `string const&` or just `string`?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. You cannot use `kurzbez` before declaring it

Comment: @crashmstr: My thought was: I have a vector with elements of string type, so define a function with a string argument, and call the function with that vector element.

Comment: `void datei_oeffnen(string* var[]);` does not declare a function that takes a `std::string` argument. That would have less `*`, `[`, and `]`.

Comment: @Eljay: Tried, but there were other errors.

Comment: @tobi303: I declare it before I use it, i simply wrote it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the argument from string *[] to just string (or even better string const &), for what you are doing there is no need to pass a pointer to the element in the vector.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. 

Can this be modified to work with a pointer?